# Terraform map(object) variable in BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am deploying Terraform code through a Bitbucket pipeline and am having an problem when parsing a map of objects variable in the pipeline. Below is the variable:

```
variable "images" {
  type = map(object({
    port = number
  }))
}
```

Below is how the variable value is defined in the BitBucket Pipeline variables:

```
"{"image_one"={port=1000}"image_two"={port=2000}}"
```

When the pipeline runs, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Extra characters after expression
│ 
│   on <value for var.images> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ An expression was successfully parsed, but extra characters were found
│ after it.
```

Below is the command within `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` on how the variable is called within the pipeline:

```
terraform apply -var images="$IMAGES" -auto-approve
```

Any advice on how to get the map of objects to execute through the pipeline would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to clarify your question. Its not even possible to get the error you are getting, as your `"{"image_one"={port=1000}"image_two={port=2000}}"` has unbalanced `"`.

Comment: My apologies, I have fixed the variable in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is your actual code, and not again some mistake you did when making the question, then you are missing a comma between arguments. It should be:

```
"{"image_one"={port=1000}, "image_two"={port=2000}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, unfortunately adding a comma between arguments is resulting in the same error.

Comment: I am using Terraform version 1.0.0

Comment: @DaveMichaels The IMAGES is correct now. This means that your issue must be originating from outside of what you posted in the question.

Comment: OK. I am able to run locally without the commas in the variable. I will look at the pipeline syntax.

Comment: @DaveMichaels You need to have comma. This probably means that your real code is different that what you posted in the question.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was with the outer " ". I removed those and it worked!